# Dynamically add Button id based on the button click show div in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I had one for-loop in that for loop one div data and summit button.

Code i tried :

```
 for(i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
           var job = '<div class="job-headers">';
           job += '<h3>'+response.data[i].job_title+'</h3>';
           job += '<h5>'+response.data[i].location+'</h5>';
           job += '<h5>'+response.data[i].description+'</h5>';
           job += '<h5> Created on :'+response.data[i].created_at+'</h5>';
           job += '<h5> Status :'+response.data[i].job_status+'</h5>';
     **show****job += '<div><h2>Title: ' + response.data[i].job_title + <h2>;
          job  += '<h2>Title: ' + response.data[i].job_role + <h2>';    
          $job+= '</div>'
         ****** job += '<input type="submit" class="submit-button" value="submit">';
           $(".submit-button").click(function() {
                     $(this).prev('div').toggle();
                  });

                  job += '</div>';
                   $('#job-preview').append(job);
                 }
             });
        });
```

first button only show the first div second button not working? any ides???

Comment: If the div/button gets created the error might be in your for loop. Can you add it please, too?

Comment: Assuming the first two lines are looped, then that's your issue. You're creating multiple elements with the same id which is invalid. Use a class instead.

Comment: but that class name itself automatically change right . so only based on the button click it will check the div and display result that one was my question bro

Comment: `but that class name itself automatically change right` No, not at all. I don't know why you'd think that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're creating multiple elements with the same `id` attribute in your loop. This is invalid as they must be unique within the DOM. This is the reason it only works for the first button.

To fix this problem remove the `id` attribute and use a common class on the button elements. Then you can create a single event handler bound to all those buttons. You can use DOM traversal to only toggle the `div` relative to the clicked button, like this:

```js
var response = {
  data: [{
    job_title: 'Title 1',
    job_role: 'Role 1'
  }, {
    job_title: 'Title 2',
    job_role: 'Role 2'
  }]
}

for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
  var job = '<div class="job-headers">';
  job += '<h3>' + response.data[i].job_title + '</h3>';
  // other fields...
  job += '<div><h2>Title: ' + response.data[i].job_title + '</h2>';
  job += '<h2>Title: ' + response.data[i].job_role + '</h2></div>'
  job += '<input type="submit" class="submit-button" value="submit">';
  job += '</div>';
  $('#job-preview').append(job);
}

$(".submit-button").click(function() {
  $(this).prev('div').toggle();
})
```

```css
.job-headers>div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="job-preview"></div>
```

Comment: job += '<div>Status: ' + response.data[i].job_title + '</div>';
  job += '<input type="submit" class="submit-button" value="submit">';

i need to show this status only bro and also i can't add css fies . two div's there bro.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean there

Comment: I updated the answer to include a working snippet so you can see the logic in action. Hopefully that makes it clearer for you.

Comment: Also, please stop calling everyone 'bro'. It's rather informal and a little unprofessional in this environment.

Comment: i think now question is clear . the show which i mentioned that div only hide /show  based on the button .otherwise top data will be static

Comment: The structure is the same, and this answer still works. Have you even tried the example I posted above?

Comment: please tell me where exactly i can add this line  .job-headers>div {
  display: none;
}

Comment: In your CSS stylesheet

Comment: now working fine. the this is i missed the close bracket that's why second option not worked.

Comment: now i had one json in  inside column  certification :  ["CCNA - Data Center"] 
 job += '<h2>Title: ' + response.data[i].certifications + '</h2></div>' in this i need to display but i had confusion for this json remove.any ideas??